# Pass DbContext to class library

Tags: class, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1

I am developing an API to get data from the database using the entity framework. I have a **class library** to handle my generic tasks, including Repository, UnitOfWork etc. My UnitOfWork class is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AppPermission.Data.DataContext;
using AppPermission.Data.Models;
using AppPermission.Data.Repositories;

namespace AppPermission.Common.UnitOfWork
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly DbContext dbContext;
       

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            dbContext = context;
        }


        public int SaveChanges()
        {
            return dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            dbContext.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

      
    }
}
```

My API's ConfigureServices is as below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }
```

I want to pass AppDbContext registered in the API startup to UnitOfWork in the class library. There were a couple of solutions in StackOverflow using(services.BuildServiceProvider), but the connection is disposed of after the first API call (GetAll). Is there any way of doing it? If I place my UnitOfWork in the API project itself and changing the constructor in UnitOfWork to accept AppDbContext, it works fine?

Comment: Why does your `UnitOfWork` object implement `IDisposable`? You should never dispose objects that were generated by your DI pipeline. The pipeline takes care of that for you. Remove the implementation of `IDisposable` from `UnitOfWork` and remove the `void Dispose()...` code and everything will work fine.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for your comments. This is what is recommended in this document from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. Am I missing something here? Do you know how to pass dbcontext to a class library.

Comment: The linked document is quite old (from 2013), obsolete and the UOW implementation there does not use DI, but allocates `DbContext` in the constructor, that's why it needs `IDisposable` to `Dispose` it. Your implementation is different, so  see the comment by @Andy. There is nothing special you need to do in order to make DI inject the `DbContext` into your class, regardless of being it in class library or not.

Comment: And btw, implementing Generic Repository and UOW on top on EF Core nowadays is considered "anti-pattern", because EF Core already implements them with `DbSet<T>` and `DbContext` respectively.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. I will try it then. Do you have any documents so that I can go through the recommended practice now?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use Generic `UnitOfWork` :

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : DbContext
```

class constructor :

```
public UnitOfWork(TContext context, ILogger<UnitOfWork<TContext>> logger){}
```

Then add it to IServiceCollection like this :

```
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork<MonitoringDbContext>>();
```